# Assembly : Converting x86 code to x64 for a simple example

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, nasm

While I'm learning x64 assembly, I'm trying to make add method to add two integers and return integer using assembly.
I had the working code with x86 and I tried to convert to x64

simply I changed the registers' names to be that of x64 and the object file generated without errors but when I use it inside my C function I always get sum = 0.

I think there's a problem with the arguments location and I didn't find a good documentation for such issues.

```
section .text
    global addi
addi:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     rax,[rbp+12]
    mov     rdx,[rbp+8]
    add     rax, rdx
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86-64 has a calling conversion defined by amd, all toolchain for this platform should follow this:

- 1st argument -> rdi
- 2nd          -> rsi
- 3rd          -> rdx
- 4th          -> rcx
- 5th          -> rax

so it should look like:

```
section .text
    global addi
addi:
    mov rax, rsi
    add rax, rdi
    ret
```

Comment: Actually, this calling convention does not apply to x86_64 _in general_, but to SystemV-like systems (Linux and friends). If you're on Windows, there's another calling convention for x86_64, where only the first four arguments are passed in registers (rcx, rdx, r8. r9).

Answer (score 2):

The x64 ABI mandates that the first few arguments are passed in the registers, not on the stack.

See [Stack frame layout on x86-64](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/) for a nice explanation.